# Unexpected T vs &T as type parameter in Rust

Tags: rust

I'm genericising a `Graph` that I wrote. Current signature is

```
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Graph<T: Clone + Hash + Eq> {
    nodes: HashMap<T, Node<T>>,
    edges: HashMap<T, Vec<Edge<T>>>
}

#[derive(PartialEq, Debug)]
pub struct Node<T: Clone + Hash + Eq> {
    pub id: T,
    pub x: f64,
    pub y: f64
}

#[derive(PartialEq, Debug)]
pub struct Edge<T: Clone + Hash + Eq> {
    pub id: T,
    pub from_id: T,
    pub to_id: T,
    pub weight: i64
}
```

I'm using it in a specific function and the calls to other functions are failing to compile.

First, the use:

```
fn reducer<T>(graph: Graph<T>, untested_nodes: HashSet<T>, mut results: Vec<HashSet<T>>) -> Graph<T>
   where T: Clone + Hash + Eq {
    match untested_nodes.iter().next() {
        None => {
            collapsed_graph(&graph, &results)
        }
        Some(root) => {
            let connected_nodes = explore_from(&root, &graph);
            let difference = untested_nodes.difference(&connected_nodes)
                                           .cloned()
                                           .collect();
            results.push(connected_nodes);
            reducer(graph,
                    difference,
                    results
                    )
        }
    }
}
```

The signature of `explore_from`

```
fn explore_from<T: Clone + Hash + Eq>(root: &T, graph: &Graph<T>) -> HashSet<T> {
```

The compiler error:

```
   Compiling efficient_route_planning v0.1.0 (file:///Users/stuart/coding/efficient_route_planning)
src/connected_component.rs:19:55: 19:61 error: mismatched types:
 expected `&weighted_graph::Graph<&T>`,
    found `&weighted_graph::Graph<T>`
(expected &-ptr,
    found type parameter) [E0308]
src/connected_component.rs:19             let connected_nodes = explore_from(&root, &graph);
                                                                                    ^~~~~~
src/connected_component.rs:19:55: 19:61 help: run `rustc --explain E0308` to see a detailed explanation
src/connected_component.rs:20:56: 20:72 error: mismatched types:
 expected `&std::collections::hash::set::HashSet<T>`,
    found `&std::collections::hash::set::HashSet<&T>`
(expected type parameter,
    found &-ptr) [E0308]
src/connected_component.rs:20             let difference = untested_nodes.difference(&connected_nodes)
                                                                                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/connected_component.rs:20:56: 20:72 help: run `rustc --explain E0308` to see a detailed explanation
src/connected_component.rs:23:26: 23:41 error: mismatched types:
 expected `std::collections::hash::set::HashSet<T>`,
    found `std::collections::hash::set::HashSet<&T>`
(expected type parameter,
    found &-ptr) [E0308]
src/connected_component.rs:23             results.push(connected_nodes);
                                                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/connected_component.rs:23:26: 23:41 help: run `rustc --explain E0308` to see a detailed explanation
error: aborting due to 3 previous errors
Could not compile `efficient_route_planning`.
```

The full code: https://github.com/shterrett/efficient_route_planning/blob/generic-graph/src/connected_component.rs#L19

As far as I can tell, everything should be `&Graph<T>`, not `&Graph<&T>`. I'm not sure where the error is.

Versions:

```
% multirust show override
multirust: default toolchain: stable
multirust: default location: /Users/xxxxxx/.multirust/toolchains/stable

rustc 1.8.0 (db2939409 2016-04-11)
cargo 0.9.0-nightly (8fc3fd8 2016-02-29)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem seem to be here

```
let connected_nodes = explore_from(&root, &graph);
```

`untested_nodes.iter().next()` returns `Option<&T>`, so the match `Some(root)` makes `root: &T`. This implies that `&root` is `&&T`, and the inferred `T` in `explore_from` is `&T` (`T` of `reducer`). I expect that removing the reference from `root` fix this:

```
let connected_nodes = explore_from(root, &graph);
```